# How can I highlight current page in MVC 3 using RenderAction inside another view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, highlight, renderaction, current-page

I have tried these:
http://developerstyle.posterous.com/highlighting-current-page-in-mvc-3-slick-tric

[ASP.NET MVC - Current Page highlighting in navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289909/asp-net-mvc-current-page-highlighting-in-navigation)

[ASP.net MVC - Navigation and highlighting the "current" link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099621/asp-net-mvc-navigation-and-highlighting-the-current-link)

none of the above solutions work in a RenderAction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`ParentActionViewContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.parentactionviewcontext.aspx).

Comment: ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] gives me the name of the PartialView in this case MemberHeader. Not the Action that I am calling, like "Memberships" and so on

Comment: I have tried the above solutions directly in the View(), not through RenderAction and that is working.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confusing, not model, but route values.

Comment: Ok, stopped being lazy, looked around, and changed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What is it that's not working? Do you not get a "selected" class in the Html ? Or is it your css that's the problem?? The links you have provided all seems like working examples.

I've never tried this, but you should be able to get the current "page" like this:

```
String controller = String.Empty;
if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("controller")) {
    controller = (String)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
}
String action = String.Empty;
if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("action")) {
    action = (String)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
}
String area = String.Empty;
if (ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens.ContainsKey("area")) {
    area = (String)ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
}
```

Then it should be a matter of casing and comparing these information with the links you create.