# Html.ActionLink visited

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I'm having problems to include a css class in a Html.ActionLink. Actually, I search and found a code like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Performances", "Details", "Productions", 
    new { name = item.show , year = item.year }, 
    new {@class = "button"}
```

But the problem is it is not working. May be because I already include the css in  and

blocks? My code is like this:

```
<ul id="menuTop">
    <li id="menu-link-1">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", null, null, new { @class = "link-1-visited" })</li>
    <li id="menu-link-2">@Html.ActionLink("Produtos", "Products", null, null, new { @class = "link-2-visited" })</li>
    <li id="menu-link-3">@Html.ActionLink("Fale Conosco", "ContactUs", null, null, new { @class = "link-3-visited" })</li>
    <li id="menu-link-4">@Html.ActionLink("Quem Somos", "AboutUs", null, null, new { @class = "link-4-visited" })</li>
</ul>
```

I want the button get the css class when it is clicked. Do you have any idea?

Thanks for any sugestions.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set a css such as:

```
.link-1-visited:visited { color:#a00; }
```

Should set the link once clicked to red.

Comment: But the problem is I want to change the focus, unterstood? When I click in one of them, I want the button clicked before turn to normal again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099621/asp-net-mvc-navigation-and-highlighting-the-current-link